# WGET download default web page from domain

Tags: linux, http, wget

How do I can download the default web page from a domain using wget ? Example:

*www.mydomain.com* returns **index.html** as default page and *www.newdomain.com* returns **default.html** as default page. So, using wget as `wget [options] www.mydomain.com` must download index.html and `wget [options] www.newdomain.com` must download default.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget [options] www.mydomain.com/index.html
wget [options] www.newdomain.com/default.html
```

`Wget` supports filenames not just domain names.

You will never know what the default name of a file is (as a end user) only the server knows this. When you send a response to www.domain.com what the webserver for www.domain.com gets is `GET /` the webserver then looks in the / directory and discovers what the default file is (index.html, default.html or anything else the server admin has set as the default. You then just get sent that copy back. So you don't need to do anything as the end user to get the default page, it just happens by itself.

Comment: Yes but if I don't know what's the default page file? And if I want to use it on a script?

Comment: You never know what the default page is requesting / is enough. See my answer edit to clarify @DontVoteMeDown